# Convert from Excel xls to xlsx in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, xls, xlsx

Is there any gem/plugin/code snippet which will Convert from Excel xls to xlsx using ruby

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have excel installed, you should be able to use win32ole (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/win32ole/rdoc/index.html) to script Excel.  The easiest technique would probably be to rename the file as a .xlsx file, then have Excel open it and save it.  That's probably easier than trying to script your way through a "save as" operation.

It's not a Ruby solution, but I've also scripted the Excel interface using AutoIt.

Answer (score 0):

[roo](http://roo.rubyforge.org/) is the only option that springs to mind

**EDIT**

Although [this link](http://www.getharvest.com/blog/2010/08/how-to-generate-excel-files-with-ruby/) demonstrates writing xlsx files

Comment: I'm not sure how useful roo will be here.  Their website says that it's currently limited to read-only access for Excel spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel installed you can use the following method to convert a xls file into a xlsx file:

```
require 'win32ole'

def xls2xlsx(path, target = nil)
  raise ArgumentError unless path =~ /.xls\Z/
  raise ArgumentError unless File.exist?(path)

  target = path + 'x' unless target # Save the workbook. / must be \  
  puts "convert %s to %s" % [path, target]

  # Create an instance of the Excel application object
  xl = WIN32OLE.new('Excel.Application')
  # Make Excel visible  1=visible 0=not visible
  xl.Visible = 1
  #~ xl.Interactive = false  #visible, but no input allowed
  #~ xl.ScreenUpdating = false  #make it faster
  xl.DisplayAlerts = false  #No alerts like "don't overwrite
  # Add a new Workbook object      
  wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(File.expand_path(path))

  wb.SaveAs(File.expand_path(target).gsub!(/\//, '\\'), 51 ) #excel 2007
  # Close the workbook
  wb.Close
  # Quit Excel
  xl.Quit
end
```

---

If you need th other way (xlsx to xls) you can use:

```
def xlsx2xls(path, target = nil)
  raise ArgumentError unless path =~ /.xlsx\Z/
  raise ArgumentError unless File.exist?(path)

  target = path.chop unless target # Save the workbook. / must be \  
  puts "convert %s to %s" % [path, target]

  # Create an instance of the Excel application object
  xl = WIN32OLE.new('Excel.Application')
  # Make Excel visible  1=visible 0=not visible
  xl.Visible = 1
  #~ xl.Interactive = false  #visible, but no input allowed
  #~ xl.ScreenUpdating = false  #make it faster
  xl.DisplayAlerts = false  #No alerts like "don't overwrite
  # Add a new Workbook object      
  wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(File.expand_path(path))

  wb.SaveAs(File.expand_path(target).gsub!(/\//, '\\'), -4143 ) #excel97_2003_format 
  # Close the workbook
  wb.Close
  # Quit Excel
  xl.Quit
end
```

I use the 2nd method in combination with [axlsx](https://rubygems.org/gems/axlsx/) to get a xls-file. First I create a xlsx with axslx, then I convert it via winole into a xls.